# Question regarding Google Adsense

Tags: blogger, google-adsense

I monetized [my blogspot weblog](http://missingfaktor.blogspot.com) a few hours ago. However the ads do not seem to appear yet. What could possibly be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see your ads just fine. Maybe you have an ad block add-on installed on your browser that blocks the ads from appearing?

Comment: Wow, they appeared! :D Thanks anyway. +1 and a green tick too. Enjoy!